# Sorting linked list average at end

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I have to write function which sorts list in specific way, I have singly linked list of ints and I have to find average of all numbers in list and put all nodes which are above average at end of list. I can't create new list I have to work on given list. How can I accomplish it?I have to do something like this?

1. Calculate average
2. Find node which is above average save data inside it and delete
3. Malloc newnode and add data to the newnode and link it to end of list
4. repeat?

Is this method right? Could I somehow unlink given node and add it at end of my list so deleting and re-creating aren't needed?

Comment: Please read: http://sscce.org! Can you give an example of what you tried? Where you're getting problems or blocked?

Comment: If all you are doing is rearranging your data, you don't necessarily need to create new links, their pointers can instead change what they point to. Start by drawing a diagram of the steps involved for a function that takes any link and moves it to the end.

Comment: about your question, more specifically: to sum up, you say you want to take all nodes that are above average, and push them at end of list. But how do you want them to be, at the end of the list? Do you want to place them in the order you're finding them? Do you want to push them sorted in increasing order? decreasing order? or it does not matter?

Comment: Malloc is expensive. Since you're only moving nodes, I think it would be much more efficient to just update the references of your pointers ("move" the node to the end of the list if it's above average").

How to do that? That depends on your list implementation, but if you have a "next" pointer, that's a good place to start.

Comment: to complete what @leonardo is saying, you can change the value of the found node, and update the references of the `next` pointer.